Recover lost code after stash and checkout
I seem to have misplaced (that's my hope) dozens of hours worth of work. Here is the history of what I did to my Git repo:

I had worked on some code modifications that I wanted to temporarily stash and revert to the previous commit. I had 'Branch A' checked out at the time.
git stash
git checkout 44f7b43f355e30e15ab9081c2f8e92188277ca53 (I think this is where I went wrong - this was the previous commit I wanted)
git revert 44f7b43f355e30e15ab9081c2f8e92188277ca53 (Clearly I didn't know what I was doing)
git checkout 44f7b43f355e30e15ab9081c2f8e92188277ca53
I now had my previous commit code.
git stash apply (I wanted to move back forward with my previous changes)
git stash pop (At this point I assumed I was back to where I wanted to be working on Branch A. I saw all my recent changes present again.)
Dozens of hours worth of work done. What I didn't realize is that the command prompt still showed this: vscode ➜ /workspaces/git/aws-shared_network-terraform/terraform (7c76f7e) indicating I wasn't actually in Branch A.
ran a commit in vscode
ran a sync in vscode. I received an error that I needed to checkout a branch first to sync.
I checked out Branch A.
"oh poop" moment because all my work disappeared.
git checkout 44f7b43f355e30e15ab9081c2f8e92188277ca53 (Code was not restored)

I am now sitting at:
vscode ➜ /workspaces/git/aws-shared_network-terraform/terraform (44f7b43) $ 
Is there a way to recover this?
I found that if I run git log --reflog I see my commit from today:
commit 9746368659f680c934fe97e7c70881ae4882400f
Author: Me
Date:   Wed Apr 3 17:46:13 2024 +0000

    enable cdn redirect and cleanup

I don't want to do anything else until someone provides direction.

Since you can see the commit in reflog, you can give it a branch name to keep it alive (and provide reassurance), with eg. git branch temporary 9746368659f680c934fe97e7c70881ae4882400f

Then decide whether to merge temporary into an existing branch, or reset an existing branch to that, or whatever.

I think you will be much better of if you stop using git stash and instead use normal, temporary commits instead. Then you will not get into trouble like you had here or any of the other the dangerous, complicated quirks that stash have.

You're safe since you did commit your changes and they're in the reflog. The only thing that's missing is they're not part of a named branch. To fix that:

Check out Branch A.
Run git cherry-pick 9746368659f680c934fe97e7c70881ae4882400f to add your commit to Branch A.

(Note: It won't literally add that commit hash to the branch. It will replay the commit on the branch as if you had committed to Branch A originally. You'll get a new commit with the same contents and commit message but different hash.)

If you feel unsecure, you can always make a temporary copy of your repo just to make sure that if something goes wrong you still have a copy from before the mistake.
Now, you could
git show 9746368659f680c934fe97e7c70881ae4882400f

If you see your changes, then things look good.
You can create a branch if you want via
git checkout 9746368659f680c934fe97e7c70881ae4882400f
git branch my-temporary-branch

Now,
git diff A my-temporary-branch

if this looks good, then merge
git merge A

do your tests. If everything works, do
git diff A my-temporary-branch

if you like the changes, do
git checkout A
git merge my-temporary-branch

test again and if everything goes well, then
git branch d my-temporary-branch

